# Is there a guaranteed priority in Swing events of the same type?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, event-listener

Quick example: I have a JButton with two `ActionListener`. Will they be executed in a guaranteed order? Is it the same for all kind of `EventListener` of the same type?

```
JButton b = new JButton();
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("event 1");
});
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("event 2");
});
```

Comment: IIRC, event listeners are called in reverse order of being added, but I don't think that's guaranteed. If you need a guarantee, create a composite listener?

Comment: I solved my specific problem by passing a `Callable` to an `ActionListener`

Answer (score 0):

As @daniu mentioned in the comment section, when a button (or any component) have multiple listeners of the same type (in our example we have 2 action listeners in a `JButton`) they will be fired from last to first. The comment inside `AbstractButton#fireActionPerformed` makes it pretty clear:

```
protected void fireActionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    // Guaranteed to return a non-null array
    Object[] listeners = listenerList.getListenerList();
    ActionEvent e = null;
    // Process the listeners last to first, notifying
    // those that are interested in this event
    for (int i = listeners.length-2; i>=0; i-=2) {
        if (listeners[i]==ActionListener.class) {
            // Lazily create the event:
            if (e == null) {
                  String actionCommand = event.getActionCommand();
                  if(actionCommand == null) {
                     actionCommand = getActionCommand();
                  }
                  e = new ActionEvent(AbstractButton.this,
                                      ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED,
                                      actionCommand,
                                      event.getWhen(),
                                      event.getModifiers());
            }
            ((ActionListener)listeners[i+1]).actionPerformed(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course one example to test it yourself is pretty easy to be created:

```
public class ListenersTest extends JFrame {

    public ListenersTest() {
        super("tests");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JButton button = new JButton("press me");
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            button.addActionListener(new Listener(i));
        }
        add(button);

        setSize(400, 400);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    }

    private static class Listener implements ActionListener {
        private int id;

        private Listener(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("My ID is:" + id);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new ListenersTest().setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

If you press the button you will get:

> My ID is:5 My ID is:4 My ID is:3 My ID is:2 My ID is:1

Comment: Yes, this is the current implementation but it is not guaranteed in the Java spec.